# Does French past participle PRISE explain Modern English meanings of "comPRISE"?

Tags: etymology, french

> **[compose](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=compose), [comprise](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=comprise).** Compose means “to make up” or “to constitute.” Comprise means “to be composed of” or “to consist of.” *The American Digest System comprises nine units and a current supplement (or is composed of). Nine units and a current supplement compose the American Digest System (or are comprised in).*

I just noticed that "pose" in comPOSE is present tense. But PRISE in comPRISE is French past participle. What extent does PRISE explain the above Modern English meanings of comPRISE? PRISE means "taken" or "seized" in French.

Just curious why comPRISE was formed with French past participle of *comprendre*, not present tense. This makes me guess Modern English meanings of comPRISE are related to PRISE?

Bahrych, Merino. *Legal Writing and Analysis in a Nutshell 5th edition* (2017). 357.

Comment: Many English verbs take their form from Latin passive participles; *(com)pose* is one example (the Latin present stem is *pon*).  French *comprendre, compris* is literally ‘take together’, and thus ‘include’, which makes more sense to me than the other modern French sense ‘understand’!

Comment: @AntonSherwood English inherited the French "comprehension" and kept its meaning. This should help to make sense out of the meaning of *compris* which was by the way already there in the Latin *comprehendere*.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/comprise

Answer (score 1):

Comprise indeed didn't pick *comprendre* but the past participle *compris* as its basis.

*Comprendre* means according to its Latin etymology *comprehendere* "to take together".

Old French had both *comprehender* and *comprendre* verbs with various meanings including "to grasp, to understand" which gave one of the modern meanings of the French *comprendre*, but also to seize/invade (lost in modern French) and to contain/include
which is alive in both French and the English "comprise".

*Comprise* isn't a unique case of past participle derivation. Here are a few examples:

Still from *-prendre* verbs:

- to reprise, French past part. *repris* vs *reprendre* (take back)
- to surprise, French p.p. *surpris* vs *surprendre* (same meaning)

From *-faire* verbs:

- to defeat, from old French *desfait* (now *défait*) instead of *défaire*.
- to forfeit, French *forfait* instead of *forfaire*.
- to counterfeit, French *contrefait* vs *contrefaire*.

Other stems:

- to remise, French p.p. *remis* instead of the infinitive *remettre* (send back).
- to corrupt, from the Latin past. part. *corruptus* instead of infinitive *corrumpere* (French *corrompre*)

Answer (score 0):

Your etymology is not exact; "comprise" does come from French, but the French word at the origin is "compris(e)", past participle of "comprendre".  As to the French word "explaining" the English, you can't indulge in such characterizations without quoting them and making clear what you intend to convey thereby. The meaning of the  word "comprendre" can only provide certain clues; for instance the meaning "to grasp with the mind" is obsolete and insofar as that goes, "comprendre is certainly no "explanation". However, in the sense "include, contain", it is true that one of the meanings of "comprendre" is quite similar in French.

(Etymology from the *SOED*)